# Linux Replace tab with 4 spaces

Tags: linux, keyboard, centos

I was wondering if there is a way to remap my tab key to produce 4 spaces instead? I know how to do it in Vi/Vim but I would like that to work anywhere on my computer. I am running CentOS. I have to program using only 4 spaces instead of tab but I am using a couple oft IDEs so I would like to make it work everywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's what you want http://editorconfig.org/

best regards

Comment: Thank you! Didn't try it yet but it seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I would like eclipse to be in the list of ide but I can probably do it snother way in eclipse. Tks